# receiver type 'AppDelegate' for instance message does not declare a method with selector ERROR

Tags: objective-c, appdelegate

Can't seem to nail this issue here. Any idea what needs to be changed? I'm using Xcode 4.2.

**Error:** AppDelegate.m:23:6: error: receiver type 'AppDelegate' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'setupHUD' [4]

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    LoginViewController *loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC];
    navCon.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = navCon;
    [self setupHUD];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}


- (void) setupHUD
{
    //setup progress hud
    self.HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
    [self.window addSubview:self.HUD];
    self.HUD.dimBackground = YES;
    self.HUD.minSize = CGSizeMake(150.f, 150.f);
    self.HUD.delegate = self;
    self.HUD.isCancelButtonAdded = YES;
    self.HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Prior to Xcode 4.3](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/), you need to forward declare methods called within the same `@implementation` block, so make sure to add the declaration of `setupHUD` to either the class extension (the list of declarations inside AppDelegate.m that starts with `@interface AppDelegate ()`), or the `@interface` block in AppDelegate.h.

For example, in AppDelegate.m:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
// Other declarations...
- (void)setupHUD;
@end
```

Or in AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
// Other declarations
- (void)setupHUD;
@end
```